# Bash shells script 101 - variable definition, pbcopy, etc

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, encodeuricomponent, pbcopy

I am trying to create a (my first) bash script, but I need a little help. I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Write a LaTeX equation:" 
read -e TeXFormula

URIEncoded = node -p "encodeURIComponent('$(sed "s/'/\\\'/g" <<<"$TeXFormula")')"

curl http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$URIEncoded -o /Users/casparjespersen/Desktop/notetex.gif | pbcopy
```

I want it to:

1. Require user input (LaTeX equation)
2. URIEncode user input (the top result in Google was using node.js, but anything will do..)
3. Perform a cURL call to this website converting equation to a GIF image
4. Copy the image to the placeholder, so I can paste it to a note taking app like OneNote, Word, etc.

My script is malfunctioning in the following:

- `URIEncoded` is undefined, so there is something wrong with my variable definition.
- When I copy using `pbcopy` the encrypted text content of the image is copied, and not the actual image. Is there a workaround for this? Otherwise, the script could automatically open the image and I could manually Cmd + C the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> URIEncoded is undefined, so there is something wrong with my variable
>   definition.

The line should read

```
URIEncoded=$(node -p "encodeURIComponent('$(sed "s/'/\\\'/g" <<<"$TeXFormula")')")
```

without spaces around the `=` sign, and using the `$()` construct to actually perform the command, otherwise, the text of the command would be assigned to the variable.

> When I copy using pbcopy the encrypted text content of the
>   image is copied, and not the actual image. Is there a workaround for
>   this? Otherwise, the script could automatically open the image and I
>   could manually Cmd + C the content.

`pbcopy` takes input from stdin but you are telling `curl`  to write the output to a file rather than stdout. Try simply

```
curl http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$URIEncoded | pbcopy
```

or, for the second option you describe

```
curl http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$URIEncoded -o /Users/casparjespersen/Desktop/notetex.gif && open $_
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I try to do the `curl http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$URIEncoded | pbcopy` solution, I get an error that `pbcopy` is undefined. How is that?

Comment: Weird. Try writing the full path `/usr/bin/pbcopy` ?

Comment: Same result. Even though if I run `pbcopy` (or with full path) outside the script, it works. Could it be because I have located my script as `/bin/notetex`?

Comment: What is the output of `which pbcopy` when run from your script?

Comment: This is weird.. Output is: `/usr/bin/pbcopy`

Comment: Okay. I just tried re-writing it and `pbcopy` works now. But when I paste the content it just inserts a text e.g. "GIF89aB" instead of the actual GIF image.

Comment: Works with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919403/set-clipboard-to-image-pbcopy