# Copy Image to Clipboard from Bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have an image on the desktop,

```
    $ ls
    1.png
```

I'd like to copy it to the clipboard,and tried

```
    $ pbcopy 1.png

    ^C
```

I should terminate the process manually.

How to copy image to clipboard, so I can paste them around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919403/set-clipboard-to-image-pbcopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install xclip

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Use -t to specify format

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i 1.png
```

Comment: OP seems to be using macOS.

Comment: And this post if off topic